# Shebangs in scalac code

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, shebang, scalac

The scala interpreter allows shebangs, but strangely, scalac borks on them. Are there any tricks like [these](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Multiline_shebang) to get around this flaw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#! in scala must be closed with !#. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0") >/dev/null; pwd -P)
classes_dir=${script_dir}/build/classes
src_dir=${script_dir}/src

mkdir -p ${classes_dir}
scalac -d ${classes_dir} $(find ${src_dir} -name '*.scala')

exec /usr/bin/scala -classpath ${classes_dir} "$0" "$@"
!#
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not strip them transparently before invoking `scalac` in your build script?

Comment: I'd like to not have to strip any code. I'm willing to use obscure shebang syntax if necessary to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a question of "obscure shebang syntax", but rather a "language specification" issue.
The [Wikipedia article on Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) does mention:

> The contents of the shebang line will be automatically ignored by the interpreter, because the `#` character is a comment marker in many scripting languages.
>   **Some language interpreters that do not use the hash mark to begin comments, such as [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_%28programming_language%29), still may ignore the shebang line**.

So if scalac hasn't in its specification the directives to ignore the first lines as ["script header" like Scheme](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-app/r6rs-app-Z-H-6.html), we need to wait on your [Jira case 5179](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5179).